Problem Restoring state in Jetpack compose Navgation navigating several composables
I have this simple NavHost containing three Composables First Second and Third
@Composable
fun Navigation() {
    val controller = rememberNavController()
    Column {
        NavHost(navController = controller, startDestination = "First") {
            composable(route = "First") {
                NavigationItem(
                    title = "First",
                    navigationText = "Navigate to Second"
                ) {
                    controller.navigate("Second") {
                        restoreState = true
                    }
                }
            }
            composable(route = "Second") {
                NavigationItem(
                    title = "Second",
                    navigationText = "Navigate to Third",
                    backHandler = {
                        controller.popBackStack(
                            "First",
                            inclusive = false,
                            saveState = true
                        )
                    }
                ) {
                    controller.navigate("Third") {
                        restoreState = true
                    }
                }
            }
            composable(route = "Third") {
                NavigationItem(
                    title = "Third",
                    navigationText = "<Back",
                    backHandler = {
                        controller.popBackStack(
                            "Second",
                            inclusive = false,
                            saveState = true
                        )
                    }
                ) {
                    controller.popBackStack(
                        "Second",
                        inclusive = false,
                        saveState = true
                    )
                }
            }
        }
        BackStackListener(controller)//This is for monitoring backstack
    }

The individual NavigationItems are constructed from the composable below having a savable states
private const val TAG = "NAVIGATION_ITEM"

@Composable
fun NavigationItem(
    title: String,
    navigationText: String,
    backHandler: () -> Unit = {},
    navigate: () -> Unit
) {
    val state = rememberSaveable { mutableIntStateOf(0) }
    //val state = remember { mutableIntStateOf(0) }
    DisposableEffect(key1 = state.intValue) {
        Log.v(TAG, "Disposable effect in $title State is ${state.intValue}")
        onDispose {
            Log.v(TAG, "Maybe Disposing $title")
        }
    }

    BackHandler {
        if (backHandler != {}) {
            backHandler()
        }
    }
    Column {
        Text(title)
        Button(onClick = navigate) {
            Text(navigationText)
        }
        Button(onClick = { state.intValue += 1 }) {
            Text("Change state")
        }
        Text("State:${state.intValue}", style = TextStyle(fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold))
    }
}

My problem is the following

FirstItem is the start destination
I navigate to second Item( using restore state if any such state has been on the stack)
I navigate to third item ( using restore state if any such state has been on the stack)
I navigate BACK to SecondItem by popping the stack and saving the state
I navigate BACK to FirstItem by popping the stack and saving the state
Now the problem: If I navigate forward again from first to second It jumps to Third Item and only thirdItem is pushed onto the back stack
If I remove the last saveState in popping from ThirdItem to SecondItem, the jump from First to Third going forward will disappear but the restoration of ThirdItem will not happen going forward one more time, only restoration of SecondItem will work.

There seems to be something here I do not understand. I know that I could implement this by state hoist, view model and what not. But my purpose is to understand what is going on when saving state and restoring in navigation.
Can some one explain
I tried many combinations of pop and navigate but the crucial point seems to be
If I skip saveState in the Pop from ThirdItem to SecondItem then going forward again will work from FirstItem to SecondItem, but of course not from SecondItem to ThirdItem since no saveState has been called
But implementing the saveState in the Pop from ThirdItem to SecondItem and then going forward from FirstItem to SecondItem will result in a jump directly to ThirdItem, which seems mysterious to me. It seems that the saveState in the pop from secondItem to FirstItem has been ignored. Clearly there is something I am missing here.
